# What is this thing called and what is the correct hose order f150?

Tags: part-identification, f-150, coolant-leak

A few months ago this little box started leaking coolant (the green stuff), i took it to the mechanic to repair, charge me for it but apparently did nothing because continue leaking (just a few drops not enough to form a puddle under the truck so i just ignore it).

Fast forwarding to the present and my truck show up a light telling me to "CHECK GAUGES", again ignore it and when I parked a huge puddle was under, big leak and the truck shut off (overheating i guess). Open the hood check and the coolant reservoir was empty. Woopsie. Good news it happen less than 1km from my home so I was able to let it cool down and drive "safely" to my house and park without overheating.

Filled the reservoir, turn on the truck and a fountain of the stuff came from this little box. The bottom plastic, nipple? , that connects a hose finally broke.

Stupid me trying to fix the dammed thing unplug all 3 of the hoses (hard to reach) to fix the broken one, not even 1 minute had passed and I already forgot the order that they were plugged. Shit at least 1 of them is thicker so no big deal but the other two were the same fucking thickness so i don't know what to do now.

So anyone knows whats the name and purpose of this little box, and whats the correct order of the hoses. I am trying to find some diagrams but no luck identifying it.

Ford f-150 2007 crew cab 5.4l triton engine.

[image: Little coolant box]
[image: Slim hoses destination]
[image: Little box close up]

Comment: Its clearly NOT a factory installed option. Its some sort of remote heated assembly. Possible some sort of send us money get more horsepower device?  I’ve seen lots of odd stuff (including engine cooled EGR valves and engine cooled alternator), but this one is over my head.